# How do I modify the include path during a source install?

Tags: installation, path, compilation

I'm trying a source install (configure, make) on FreeBSD but I get this error:

```
error: foo.h: No such file or directory
```

although the file does exist at /usr/local/include/foo.h so I guess the compiler is not looking in /usr/local/include .

How do I make it do so:

LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/include"

CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"

LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/include"

haven't helped. (The install works works fine on OS 10.7 Tiger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables) environment variables:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include/:${CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH}
```